# How can I change settings in Dekko?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, appmenu, bq

While creating my first mail account in Dekko, on my new bq E5,  I just entered the wrong setting (Imap in the place of Pop). Now I am stuck: I do not find a way to change it.

More generally:

> - How can I modify anything in an App?
> - How can I deinstall an App?
> - Is there an Handling wiki?

Command lines are also welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dekko:** Press the menu on the top left → email settings. Click on the envelope/account name and slide it to the right. A red trash symbol will appear and you can delete the account.

**Uninstall:** There are two ways. You can visit the Ubuntu Store, search for the app, go to the preview screen and choose to delete it. The other way is via the home screen. Just press the icon of an installed app for a few seconds and you'll directly open the preview screen of the app.

**Wiki:** We've put up a wiki at https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Ubuntu_Touch/ (german) you can use it via translate.google.com or just download a manual from bq: http://www.bq.com/de/support/aquaris-e5-ubuntu-edition It's hidden behind "Benutzerhandbuch". Available languages are english, french, german... and several more.

**Modify:** You'll have to ask in a more specific way. Perhaps the manual will answer it for you. Otherwise ask another question concerning the app.

Comment: Thanks. Your replay sounds very good. But did you test it on an Ubuntu Touch/bq phone? Just because I do not see the way to "... slide to the right" the selected icon/name. That is by the way the reason I always tag "bq"  to my questions: to find how the hell the Developers managed it, to do without the mouse!

Comment: For the moment the problem got solved by itself: The GMX web mailer seems to be so clever, that mail began to pop up by itself, although I had entered Imap, but set the pop server name.

Comment: Yes - I'm running a bq 4.5 Ubuntu edition. I've created a screenshot showing the trash: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160126/6w9bggku.jpg

Comment: Oh yes! The path hereto is: Posteingang, Menu, E-Mail-Einstellungen, Drag to the right the Envelope Icon decovering The Trash, Trash. Thank You very much!